# Python: printing values from a list of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

I'm quite new to python, and was wondering if someone could explain me how to print values from a list of tuples.

The thing is, I have a list of tuples as such:

```
my_list = [(a1,b1),(a2,b2),(a3,b3),(a4,b4)]
```

What I want to do is get my program to print this as:

```
As   Bs
a1   b1
a2   b2
a3   b3
a4   b4
```

Hope someone can help.
Thanks

Comment: did you want to print `As`, `Bs` also?

Comment: Please post some code of what you have tried so far and where you have failed laong with any possible error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to this.

```
my_list = [('a1', 'b1'), ('a2', 'b2'), ('a3', 'b3'), ('a4', 'b4')]

for x in my_list:
    print x[0], x[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Are a1,b1,a2,b2 strings? assuming them as strings

```
my_list = [('a1','b1'),('a2','b2'),('a3','b3'),('a4','b4')]

for i,j in enumerate(my_list):
    if i == 0:
        print 'AS\tBS'
    print j[0]+'\t'+j[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
my_list = [('a1', 'b1'), ('a2', 'b2'), ('a3', 'b3'), ('a4', 'b4')]
print 'As\tBs'
for a, b in my_list:
    print '%s\t%s' % (a, b)
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out..

The list is a list of tuples, where each of the tuples consists of one string and one float.

```
for tup in my_list:
    print(tup[0], "\t", tup[1])
```

EDIT:
As I just saw, same point as what Haresh Shyara shared.

Thanks everyone :)

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking for how to print the value of your variables (a1, b1...) then you can call them from the array. For instance if you wanted to print the value of a1, you can call "my_list[0][0]". You can format it using a simple for loop. Does that answer your question?